# Prove that $x_n\to x\implies \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\leq f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ and let $M$ be a real number such that:

(i) for each $n,$ $f_n$ is continuous;
(ii) for each $x\in[0,1]$ and for each $n,$  $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)\leq M.$

Prove that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise on $[0,1]$ to a function $f$ which is lower semicontinuous.

(that is for all $\{x_n\}\subset [0,1]$ and for all $x\in [0,1],$
$x_n\to x\implies \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\leq f(x).$

Please, can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: This is not lower semicontinuity, for lower s.c. the inequality has to be the other way round.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185549/prove-liminf-limits-n-to-infty-fx-n-le-fx?rq=1)

Comment: Define $f(x)=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N} f_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{f_n\}$ is increasing and bounded above $f(x)=lim_n f_n(x)$ exists. Suppose $\lim \inf f(x_n) >f(x)$. Choose $\epsilon >0 $ such that $\lim \inf f(x_n) >f(x)+\epsilon $. There exists $n_0$ such that $f(x_n) >f(x)+\epsilon $ for $n \geq n_0$. Hence $f_k (x_{n_0}) >f(x)+\epsilon $ for some $k$. But $f(x) \geq f_k (x_{n_0})$ and this gives a  contradiction.